# Disable SSH Public Key Login for a user when her Active Directory account is disabled

Tags: linux, active-directory, ssh, pki

I have many users in my environment who deploy their public keys on the linux servers for password-less and secure login via SSH.

All these users have accounts on our Active Directory, however, when a user leaves the company and we disable her corresponding AD account, her keys are still there and she can still login to all servers that have her public keys deployed.

Is there any way I can prevent the user from logging in to a server via her public key when her AD account is disabled, locked, expired or deleted?

**Note:** We use PBIS-Open for AD authentication

Comment: You've told us very little about how this is all configured (whether you have UsePam=Yes in your opensshd config and the corresponding PAM stack might be helpful)

Comment: I can use a whole new configuration, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the user shell to `/sbin/nologin`, it might be also a different path depending on the distribution and version.

```
usermod --shell /sbin/nologin <user-name>
```

Additionally you can set the expire date as well.

```
usermod --shell /sbin/nologin --expiredate 1 <user-name>
```

Depending on your configuration, these information might also be configured in LDAP, NIS or directly in AD. In those cases you might have to execute some different commands to alter the login shell and the expiration date.

Comment: `/bin/false` is another common "no login allowed" shell, although it could allow SFTP depending on your configuration. Either way, check `/etc/shells` for an appropriate "no login" shell or add one as needed.

Comment: but how would I know which servers have the user's keys installed?

Comment: Well, if you do not have a centralized authentication like LDAP, best would be to configure the login shell on each server to disable the login.